# right click on program > "%1" %* instead of run

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, file-extension, runas

I have windows 7 and downloaded a program (.exe possibly containing a virus), but didn't install it. Then I right clicked on the program > open with > notepad (always use this program not selected), which opened notepad with an error. All programs got the notepad file icon and opened with notepad.

After searching Microsoft help pages and contacting technical support, I followed this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688326. Which solved the problem (i can now run programs). However now if I right click on a program which is supposed to say `run` as the first option it says `"%1" %*`

can someone with Windows 7 home premium tell me what it says in the three registries, it speaks about in the link.

@Amirreza Nasiri your answer is only based on a spelling mistake I made (and corrected) in the question. and therefore didn't solve the  problem.

Comment: There is no such article on the URL. "The page you are looking for may have a new location, or is no longer available."

Comment: I fixed it. it was /kb/ not /gb/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### instead of typing `"%1" %*` in the last two registries type `Run` .

thanks to Microsoft support.

apparently it just needs to be the same characters in both registries. (that's how i understood it.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the article, in the "Let me fix it myself" session steps 8 and 11 where you should change the Value data: to `"%1" %*` at both these paths:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile 
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open

You made mistake and changed it to `"%1"%*` instead of `"%1" %*`. You should note that there is a Space character between second quotation mark and second percent characters.

Comment: so i should change it back, I presume?

Comment: @743 Yes you should change it back to `"%1" %*`

Comment: +1 for fast response i spent two hours 'chatting' with Microsoft while they tried to get me to buy premium support for $150 and get all the information they could about my pc

Comment: You can get a lot of guidance on the internet without paying anything. :)

Comment: i didn't realise it would be so fast

Comment: it already has a space (I made a mistake when writing the question)  also this registry doesn't exist  `KEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open` it probably should be `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open`

Comment: I edited the answer, it was HKEY.

Comment: the missing h was from Microsoft it wasn't your fault

Comment: That's right. could you explain what did you EXACTLY done?

Comment: i did exactly how it says in the artical

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is go back to where you changed the file under exefile/open and then clear it and also clear the sub folder under open also which is called command and it will correct it back to normal seeing is that was the default values befor e the change.